# Piping to a new Command Line in Java

Tags: java, command-line, piping

I am writing a program that creates a this batch file:

`at xx:xx /interactive "cmd.exe"`

The program allows the user to select the time themselves, and on a computer running Windows XP, the command prompt spawned by this batch file should give you system level access.

However, I still need control of the system privileged cmd after it is spawned, which is where I am drawing a blank.

How does one go about piping to a command line expected to spawn in about 1 minute in the future?

Comment: Isn't it about getting `input` and `output` streams of spawned process?